# Confusing PNP transistor configuration on PCB, trying to understand how it is wired

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, schematics

I was hoping someone could help me decipher this Q4 PNP transistor. It is labeled Y2 on top of it but it didn't come out in the image. Looking around on google I see that it is a PNP transistor and looks like it is probably very similar to this one [here.](http://www.secosgmbh.com/datasheet/products/SSMPTransistor/SOT-23/SS8550.pdf)

All of the components I am worried about are pictured on the top of the PCB.

There are some strange things going on there that I am uncertain about inbetween the transistor's base and emitter, and the R7 10k (103) resistor that I am hoping a more experienced eye will be able to figure out.

Does my interpretation look sane?

[image: PNP Transistor labeled Y2]

Attempt and circuit schematic here:

[image: Attempt at sub-circuit schematic]

[image: Mirrored Back of pcb]

[image]

Comment: There's probably a via under the transistor where you are showing a connection to the collector.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It doesn't look like it. I added the image of the back mirrored as if you could look through the board.

Comment: Hi BobR. Getting things correct is really a requirement but it seems has you have started off in the wrong direction from the outset. In your text you go on about a Q1 whilst your PCB picture does not even show a Q1. Let's see if this can be straightened out before proceeding forward.

Comment: @MichaelKaras yep your right, that is supposed to be a Q4 there. Fixed.

Comment: The chances are that the tracks under the transistor don't go where you think they do.

Comment: There is not really enough of the top of the PCB shown to tie it to the other side. It might also help to know what it is exactly.